# Ruby on Rails - in 'require': cannot load such file -- omniauth/oauth, even though I installed omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, salesforce, gemfile

I am following this guide (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/omniauth-and-force-com) in hooking up Salesforce.com REST API with ruby on rails.

I'm at the part where I type in "rails generate controller sessions create", but I get an error saying that omniauth/oauth can't be found, even though I definitely installed it.

The guide also says that I need to type in

```
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.0'
gem 'httparty'
```

but whenever I do this I get an error saying "Unknown command omniauth". I'm totally new at this, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines:

```
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.0'
gem 'httparty'
```

Are meant to go in a file called `Gemfile` that is in the root of your project directory. If you are typing them into the command line, that is where you are getting hung up. You should then type `bundle install` into the command line to update the dependencies from your app and continue with the tutorial from there.

Comment: I was indeed putting them in command line and that's why it wasn't working. But even after I added them into the gem file and did the bundle install, I get this error: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'require': cannot load such file -- omniauth/oauth <LoadError>

Answer (score 1):

have you run `bundle install` from the command line after updating your `Gemfile`?

Are you sure this is the exact error message? "Unknown command omniauth", or is it undefined method `omniauth' ?. In this case you are incorrectly referencing omniauth in your code, and it is most probably not you gemfile at fault