# rake aborted! cannot load such file -- omniauth while installation devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rake

I am new to rails authentication and using `devise` for the purpose.

I am following this tutorial for installation - http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2011/01/08/devise-authentication-in-rails-3/

Following are the steps I taken to proceed for the installation -

1. `gem 'devise'` in my GEM file.
2. bundle install
3. Updated `devise.rb` and `20130320174736_devise_create_users.rb` as shown in the tutorial.
4. Run `rake db:migrate`

Following error occurred after 4th step - `rake aborted! cannot load such file -- omniauth`

[image: error]

I googled first an came up with this link - [Ruby on Rails - in 'require': cannot load such file -- omniauth/oauth, even though I installed omniauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190468/ruby-on-rails-in-require-cannot-load-such-file-omniauth-oauth-even-thou) <-- This link is suggesting to install another gem omniauth

However I checked another 2 links and they are suggesting to un comment the line `config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo'` under `monkeytasks\config\initializers\devise.rb`

2 links - [Link 1](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)  || [Link 2](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/)

I dont know which one to follow as previously I am trying to install `Act As Authenticated` but came to know it was of no use(frankly speaking I am also not sure whether devise to be used locally or not)

Let me know the correct way of handling and removing this error. If any more info needed let me know then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've enabled Omniauth inside Devise. So, just include the gem in your Gemfile and run bundler.

Include the omniauth gem in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'omniauth'
```

Then, run bundler

```
$ bundle install
```

It should be working fine now.

Note: You may have to install the used provider too. Please check the following link for more info. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: thx it works ..just one thing more I need to comment this line onfig.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo' in devise .rb

Comment: just a suggestion..is devise is a good tool to use for authentication or some updated one also available in rails as i am a beginner with rails

Comment: devise is defacto standard gem for authentication as long as rails is concerned :). so be happy to use it.